# Can I format Extj groupHeader

Tags: string-formatting, extjs4.1, trim

This is my groupFeature

```
this.myGroupingFeature = Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping', {
        groupHeaderTpl: '{name}'
    });
```

What I want is trim the first character. Is there a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution guys... to anybody who needs this... here

```
this.myGroupingFeature = Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping', {
    groupHeaderTpl: '{[values.name.substring(1)]}' }
);
```